# change the size of caption text of carousel in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a website using bootstrap framework. I've successfully made a responsive carousel, which works fine. But when I change the size of browser to mobile screen the caption covers the image or covers most of the part of image. Although I'm beginner in CSS for mobile devices.Can anyone tell me how to reduce the size of caption text   on mobile or tablet devices. Any help regarding this would be appreciated. I can't put the whole code here because it is quite big. So I'm posting the link to my website.

Here is the link to my site: [link](http://vighanesh.byethost24.com/index.html)

Comment: As you're beginner, here is something usefull for you : media queries : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). With Media Queries you can set specific styles for different window sizes and also for specific devices.

Let's say that you want to change the font-size of a CSS-rule when the width of the window is bigger than 320px and smaller than 400px. Then you can use a code snippet like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .yourclass{font-size: 14px;}
}
```